# Can't get php-fpm with Nginx to work

Tags: centos, php, nginx, php-fpm

Server: CentOs x86_64

/etc/php-fpm.d/webuser1.conf

```
[webuser1]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
user = webuser1
group = webuser1

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 15
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 2000

request_slowlog_timeout = 5
slowlog = /home/webuser1/tmp/logs/webuser1.slow.log

php_admin_value[error_log] = /home/webuser1/tmp/logs/webuser1.error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/web1.conf

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  c64p1.v.lab.gavika.com;

#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /home/webuser1/www/public;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}


# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

In Nginx logs, I have:

```
2013/05/18 15:21:52 [error] 2943#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"     while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.122.1, server: c64p1.v.lab.gavika.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "c64p1.v.lab.gavika.com"
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed your `root` directives in the wrong places.

`root` should be defined in the `server` block, not in each `location` block. This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

To resolve the issue, remove all of the `root` directives from each `location` block, and place the correct `root` directive within the `server` block, not within any `location`.

Comment: Thanks. Placing the root directive within server block solves the problem. I had built on the default configuration found in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. The package was installed from Fedora EPEL.

Comment: Yes, they ship a misconfigured default.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what Headers you are testing which give you these results?  It looks like you are just doing a Get root (/) request through a browser?

Without any more info on the input Headers or how you are testing your config, most likely you are facing a location problem in your config.

My two pieces of advice are:

1) Check out the help pages on Nginx locations.  The Nginx Wiki (http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) is a good place if you are starting.  Also, Martin Fjordvald's primer (http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/) is good on location configs.

2) If I was having a problem getting my c64p1.v.lab.gavika.com config to work, I would fall back to a simple Nginx config based on a localhost server and get the localhost config to work first.